# How to prepare elemental gallium from a mixture of gallium and aluminum nitrate?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, purification

How would one go about preparing and purifying elemental gallium from a mixture of aluminum(III) nitrate and gallium(III) nitrate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your mixture contains aluminum nitrate and gallium nitrate, then you need to separate the aluminum nitrate first. [This patent](https://www.google.com/patents/US1845224) deals with separation of various nitrates from a mixture.

When you have pure gallium nitrate, [decompose it to gallium oxide.](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10973-005-0909-x) Then [reduce gallium oxide to gallium using a reducing agent like magnesium.](http://gallium.atomistry.com/gallium_sesqui_oxide.html) (Note: hydrogen reduces gallium(III) oxide to gallium suboxide: $\ce{Ga2O3 + 2 H2 → Ga2O + 2 H2O}$)

You will find this [youtube video](https://youtu.be/ZGHEYOCfuag) of help.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for! That YouTube video was also quite helpful in learning how gallium aluminum amalgams are purified.

Comment: @ComputerCraftr glad i could help. Alternatively, you can also check t[his video.](https://youtu.be/sUSjWfBBu2Y). It shows how gallium can be extracted from gallium-aluminum alloy.